# Perl - why does my assignment from an array ref give an error

Tags: perl, reference

Fragment A below works, copying an array by dereferencing an array ref.

Fragment B, deeper in some real code, does not.  The commented-out line is not part of the real code, which works fine (%ips is a hash in which each key is an IP address and each value is a reference to an array).

But why does the commented-out line fail with the message

> Global symbol "$ips" requires explicit package name at ...

### Fragment A:

```
my $a1 = [1,2,3];
say $$a1[1];
my @a2 = @$a1;
say "@a2";
```

---

### Fragment B:

```
    else {
            # Initialise count to 1, 
            # set both dates:
        $ips{$1} = [1, $2, $2];
        # my @arr = @$ips{$1};  # error...
    }
```

Comment: Greatly obleeged to the answerers, {$ips{$1}}; works fine.

But I'm puzzled that ($ips{$1}); (round instead of curly) fails.

I'll try to find out why by RTFM...:-)
@J-L

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using code like:

```
@$ips{$1}
```

is that you think that "@" is dereferencing "$ips{$1}" (so it can be assigned to an array), but in reality that line is using "{$1}" to get an element from "@$ips".

The "@" and "$" sigils bind more tightly than "{$1}" does, so the above is closer to:

```
(@$ips) {$1}
```

than what you want, which is:

```
@ ($ips{$1})
```

To overcome this, you can tell Perl to have the "@" sigil work on "$ips{$1}" by putting "$ips{$1}" in curly brackets, like this:

```
@{$ips{$1}}
```

This way, there's no ambiguity over which happens first.

Answer (score 3):

Perl is looking for `$ips` variable as you've made mistake when dereferencing `%ips` hash. You can

```
my @arr = @{ $ips{$1} };
```

or

```
my $ref = $ips{$1};
my @arr = @$ref; # or @{ $ref }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@$ips{$1}
```

is short for

```
@{ $ips }{$1}     # Hash slice, like @hash{"a", "b", "c"}
```

but you want

```
@{ $ips{$1} }     # Array, like @array
```

---

```
Scalar         Direct           $NAME         $scalar
Scalar         By ref (simple)  $$NAME        $$scalar_ref
Scalar         By ref           $BLOCK        ${ $scalar_ref }

Array          Direct           @NAME         @array
Array          By ref (simple)  @$NAME        @$array_ref
Array          By ref           @BLOCK        @{ $array_ref }

Hash           Direct           %NAME         %hash
Hash           By ref (simple)  %$NAME        %$hash_ref
Hash           By ref           %BLOCK        %{ $hash_ref }

Hash element   Direct           $NAME{EXPR}   $hash{key}
Hash element   By ref (simple)  $$NAME{EXPR}  $$hash_ref{key}
Hash element   By ref           $BLOCK{EXPR}  ${ $hash_ref }{key}

Hash slice     Direct           @NAME{LIST}   @hash{qw( a b c )}
Hash slice     By ref (simple)  @$NAME{LIST}  @$hash_ref{qw( a b c )}
Hash slice     By ref           @BLOCK{LIST}  @{ $hash_ref }{qw( a b c )}

Array element  Direct           $NAME[EXPR]   $array[3]
Array element  By ref (simple)  $$NAME[EXPR]  $$array_ref[3]
Array element  By ref           $BLOCK[EXPR]  ${ $array_ref }[3]

Array slice    Direct           @NAME[LIST]   @array[3..5]
Array slice    By ref (simple)  @$NAME[LIST]  @$array_ref[3..5]
Array slice    By ref           @BLOCK[LIST]  @{ $array_ref }[3..5]
```